# Resharper Unit Test Runner significantly slower than NUnit console

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, nunit, resharper

Resharper Unit Test Runner runs significantly slower than nunit-console or nunit gui.

For example, 3800 tests take just over 60 seconds via nunit-console, but those same tests take over 5 minutes to run in Resharper Unit Test runner.  Why such a significant difference?

Since our test code base has grown significantly, this is really starting to slow us down.  Has anyone else experienced similar problems?  How have you dealt with it?

The Resharper Visual Studio integration is really nice, however we might need to resort to something else.

Comment: In my experience *most things* are slower when using Resharper, which is a pity really, because apart from that it's a great add-in...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the same issue and I switched to [TestDriven.Net](http://testdriven.net/), it's lightning fast.

Comment: +1 for Jamie Cansdale's TestDriven.NET.  It is a super piece of software.  However, I find Resharper's test runner to be satisfactory when running smaller test suites.

Comment: vs2010 internal test runner is also really fast. Too bad it doesn't work with nunit :(

Comment: Just my 2cents, but asside from TestDriven.Net, there's also NCrunch for this type of thing, and it is, IMHO, a must have tool right alongside resharper.

Answer (score 9):

I don't think the goal of Resharper was to provide a utility to execute an entire test suite from within Visual Studio.  That is usually the goal of a build server or test suite server running continuous integration tools (like NUnit launched from CruiseControl)

The Resharper unit test runner appears best leveraged by running small sets of unit tests to diagnose and satisfy a particular unit of code.  It allows you to create focused test suites that can be conveniently run from within the studio, debugged, repeated, and analyzed quickly without waiting for builds.

I would recommend leveraging a build server for running the complete suite of tests.

Comment: We are using a build server to run the tests, but our policy here is to try your best not to break the build before committing changes.  So we typically run all the unit tests before a commit.

Comment: R#'s test runner is very handy for quick debugging. To avoid breaking the build, you could use something like TeamCity's Personal Build or Pre-Commit options. See http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/TCD4/Personal+Build Optionally, just run NUnit from the Tools menu.

Comment: Leveraging a build server for running the complete suite of tests is a terrible idea. It produces a lot of broken builds and completely invalidates continuous deployment. Update, test all, then commit.